# Normalizing a db with interconnected m2m relations

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I have a business model of questionnaires. Each questionnaire has multiple questions and respondents. So my model looks like this:

```
table questionnaire - id
table respondent - id, name
table question - id, text
table questionnaire_respondent - id, questionnaire_id, respondent_id
table questionnaire_question -  id, questionnaire_id, question_id
table respondent_answer -  id, questionnaire_respondent_id, questionnaire_question_id, answer_text
```

The problem with model is that in `respondent_answer` I have a sort of data duplication in that questionnaire can be figured out from both `questionnaire_question_id` and `questionnaire_respondent_id` (meaning data duplication). And the second potential problem is that we can insert rows where questionnaire of question does not correspond to that of respondent questionnaire. I understand that I could safeguard myself with insert/update triggers. And yet I am seeking a way to assure this on architecture level.
since the current architecture seems not to be compliant with 5 normalization forms (not sure which one of 5).
If I failed to state the question clearly, let me know and I will try to provide an example.

The question is how could I normalize the current db architecture ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with normalization. The word doesn't mean "good design".

Answer (score 1):

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- Question QUE, worded as QUE_TXT, exists.
--
question {QUE, QUE_TXT}
      PK {QUE}
      AK {QUE_TXT}
```

```
-- Survey (list of questions) SUR exists.
--
survey {SUR}
    PK {SUR}
```

```
-- Survey SUR contains question QUE.
--
survey_question {SUR, QUE}
             PK {SUR, QUE}

FK1 {SUR} REFERENCES survey   {SUR}
FK2 {QUE} REFERENCES question {QUE}
```

```
-- User USR provided answer ANS to question QUE
-- of survey SUR.
--
user_survey_question {USR, SUR, QUE, ANS}
                  PK {USR, SUR, QUE}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user {USR}

            FK2 {SUR, QUE} REFERENCES 
survey_question {SUR, QUE}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 0):

With this model both problems are solved architecturally!

```
table questionnare_name - id, name
table question_text - id, text
table respondent - id, name
table question - id, questionnare_name (FK), question_text (FK)
table answer - id, respondent (FK), question (FK), text
```